How to Convert u-law 8000 Hz Audio Files to OPUS in Python
I'm working on a Python project where I need to convert audio files from μ-law format with an 8000 Hz sampling rate to OPUS format. The challenge is to keep the original channels separated in the conversion process. Despite several attempts with different methods and libraries, I haven't succeeded yet. I'm looking for advice or a Python library that can efficiently handle this conversion.
What I've Tried:
1- Using pydub to Load and Export Files: Attempted to load .au files with pydub and export them as OPUS. This approach resulted in ffmpeg related errors, specifically "Invalid data found when processing input".
from pydub import AudioSegment
audio_1 = AudioSegment.from_file("path/to/file1.au", format="au", frame_rate=8000)
audio_2 = AudioSegment.from_file("path/to/file2.au", format="au", frame_rate=8000)
combined_audio = AudioSegment.from_mono_audiosegments(audio_1, audio_2)
combined_audio.export("output.opus", format="opus", bitrate="32k")

2- Direct Conversion Using ffmpeg: Also tried direct conversion with ffmpeg from both the command line and within Python, specifying codecs, but kept encountering "Invalid data found when processing input".
ffmpeg -acodec pcm_mulaw -i input_file.au -ar 8000 -ac 1 output.wav

3- Playback with aplay: Interestingly, the files play back fine using aplay with specified sampling rate and format, confirming the files are not corrupted.
aplay -r 8000 -f MU_LAW input_file.au

How can I convert audio files from u-law 8000 Hz format to OPUS format in Python, ideally keeping the original audio channels separate? Is there a specific Python library or tool that works well for this type of audio conversion?
Any help or guidance on how to tackle this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Can you provide a link to a file that has the actual ulaw 8kHz format? Note that you're asking for recommendations on libraries, and that's a reason for question closure on SO, since it's basically asking for opinions. You'd be better off picking any, try and get it to work and ask for help with the solution.

I ended up doing something like the following, I was only able to get it working through command lines, and not directly from python.
 command = [
            "ffmpeg",
            "-y",
            "-f", "mulaw", "-ar", "8000", "-ac", "1", "-i", file_path_1,
            "-f", "mulaw", "-ar", "8000", "-ac", "1", "-i",  file_path_2,
            "-filter_complex", "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2",
            "-ac", "2", "-ar", "8000", "-c:a", "libopus", combined_audio_path
        ]
        subprocess.run(command, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

If anyone has a better way I can mark it as an answer.
